# Chat com dois tipos de cliente

Tags: delphi, socket, datasnap

Desejo fazer um Chat no Delphi. Num projeto padrão onde as duas pontas estariam usando um aplicativo Delphi, tranquilo (SocketServer e ClientSocket).
Mas a minha dúvida está no seguinte: Uma das pontas estará usando um projeto Delphi e a outra estará usando um sistema Web.
Estou meio perdido, quais tecnologias (e como) deveria usar para conseguir fazer o Chat em questão?

Comment: O que é um "sistema web" ? Dê um exemplo concreto do que seria tal "sistema web". Se você está pensando num navegador web padrão (Firefox, Chrome) etc você poderia fazer a ponta Delphi se comportar como um servidor web, ou provavelmente mais adequado seria tanto o browser quanto a aplicação Delphi se comunicarem usando WebSockets.

Comment: O "sistema web" é uma intranet no qual usamos para gerenciar chamados e projetos. E desculpe a ignorância, mas como fazer o Delphi se comportar como um servidor web?  
Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode usar o DataSnap do próprio Delphi, ou se você acha que sua aplicação vai ter muitos acessos simultâneos, sugiro o mORMot